# How to get blender to write the correct diffuse color (Kd) in exported .mtl files?

Tags: materials, export

I'm using the default Diffuse BSDF for every material with custom color, but none of those colors are exported to the `.mtl` file (they all appear to be the default color `rgb(0.8, 0.8, 0.8)`).

However with the Principled BSDF shader I can export color values to the `.mtl` file but everything is darker (like `rgb(0.9, 0.7, 0.5)` becomes `rgb(0.7, 0.5, 0.3)`).

(related question, but not solved: https://blenderartists.org/t/rgb-values-wrong-when-exporting-as-obj/1179228/6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 3D file formats such as .obj/.mtl cannot represent complex node graphs, the .obj exporter add-on only considers the *Principled BSDF* when creating the file. All other shader nodes are ignored. This is documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/io_node_shaders_info.html).

I can't reproduce the problem with `Kd` having different colors in 2.81a. In case previous Blender versions applied the view transform on the scene linear RGB value from the color picker before writing the .mtl, try to temporarily set the *View Transform* to *Raw* in the *Color Management* panel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just found the darker color problem is not only `.mtl`, it's every format that contains any color inputted into blender, like vertex color in gltf/glb, and the darker the color is the more it's affected, like `rgb(1)` stays the same, `rgb(0.95)` becomes `rgb(0.8)`, `rgb(0.3)` becomes `rgb(0.1)`. Steps to reproduce on my end: 
1. fresh project with a cube
2. apply vertex color `rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` to the cube
3. export to gltf/glb
4. the result color becomes `rgb(0.21, 0.21, 0.21)`

Comment: and yes the exported color looks similar to if I set the _View Transform_ to _Raw_

Comment: I managed to get the correct color by converting linear color to sRGB on the rendering client side

Comment: Yes, vertex colors are currently treated as sRGB.